# Extending a builder pattern by chaining functions

Tags: javascript, promise, builder

I've forked Brototype and brotied it so that stuff is more readable. I'm trying to chain an additional function onto the builder pattern, but I'm lost as to where to start. (I tried adding an additional Promise callback, but that didn't work).

Here's a (truncated) copy of the original:

```
'use strict';

function Promise(object, method, args) {
    this.object = object;
    this.method = method;
    this.args = args.length > 1 ? args.slice(1) : [];
}

Promise.ok = Promise.prototype = {
    "do": function(callback, context) {
        if (this.method instanceof Function) {
            var returnValue = this.method.apply(this.object, this.args);
            if (returnValue) {
                (callback || function(){}).call(context || this.object, returnValue);
            }
        }
        return context;
    }
};

function Ok(obj) {
    if (this instanceof Ok) {
        this.obj = obj;
    } else {
        return new Ok(obj);
    }
}

Ok.true = true;
Ok.false = false;

Ok.ok = Ok.prototype = {
    "exists": function() {
        return this.obj !== void 0;
    },

    "ifExists": function(methodString) {
        var method = this.getIfExists(methodString);
        return new Promise(this.obj, method, arguments);
    }

};

module.exports = Ok;
```

How I'm using it:

```
ok(app)
    .ifExists('nested.property')
    .do(function(property){
        // something with property
    });
```

What I'd like to be able to do:

```
ok(app)
    .ifExists('nested.property')
    .do(function(property){
        // something with property
    })
    .else(function() {
        // something else
    });
```

So I tried adding:

```
Promise.ok = Promise.prototype = {
    "do": function(callback, context) {
        if (this.method instanceof Function) {
            var returnValue = this.method.apply(this.object, this.args);
            if (returnValue) {
                (callback || function(){}).call(context || this.object, returnValue);
            }
        } else {
            return new Promise(this.obj, this.else, this.args);
        }
        return context;
    },
    "else": function(callback) {
        // I don't even know? Sigh
    }
};
```

Comment: The term `Promise` is used for results of *asynchronous* computations. You should avoid it here to prevent confusion. What you are looking for seems to be *lazy* computation.

Comment: @Bergi yeah - it was originally "Bromise", and Promise was the only thing I could come up with. Good tip though - will find a better name for it.

Comment: Well, the naming conventions of the original library didn't seem to have a high standard anyway :-)